# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined(…)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I needed to refactor my stateless functional component to a class. When I did so though, I keep getting an error where it looks like React itself is undefined.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Cell } from 'fixed-data-table';

const DataCell = ({rowIndex, columnKey, data, onMessageClicked, ...props}) => {
  return (
    <Cell {...props} onClick={onMessageClicked(data[rowIndex].Id)}>
      {data[rowIndex][columnKey]}
    </Cell>
  );
};

export default DataCell;
```

to

```
import { React, Component } from 'react';
import { Cell } from 'fixed-data-table';

class DataCell extends Component {

  onCellClicked() {
    this.props.onMessageClicked(this.props.data[this.props.rowIndex].Id);
  }

  render() {
    const {rowIndex, columnKey, data, ...props} = this.props;
    return (
      <Cell {...props} onClick={onCellClicked}>
        {data[rowIndex][columnKey]}
      </Cell>
    );
  }
}

export default DataCell;
```

`bundle.js:43248 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined(…)`

and when I go to that line I see

`return _react.React.createElement(`

I don't get it. How do I debug/fix this?

My full code for this app is [here](https://github.com/magician11/vensa-test) in case the code I'm posting is not related somehow.

Thanks!

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Oh...

`import { React, Component } from 'react';`

needs to be

`import React, { Component } from 'react';`

:)

Comment: Still useful today, it was a bit of a head-scratcher. Thanks!

Answer (score 25):

The OP has answered the question it self but with no reason so here's the reason! 
{Directly quoting from https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2607#issuecomment-225911048" }

```
import { React, Component } from 'react';
```

is incorrect, should be

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

There is no named export named React. It is confusing because React is a CommonJS module, and since you’re using ES6 imports, Babel tries to map the semantics but they don’t match exactly. { Component } actually grabs Component from React itself so you might just:

```
import React from 'react'
```

and use `React.Component` instead if it’s less confusing.

Answer (score 8):

For me in TypeScript the solution was:

```
import * as React from 'react';
```

Comment: I am using Typescript 2.1.5 version and this helps me. I think there is a problem in **tsconfig.json**. Maybe `types: ['node']` will help too.