# TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of null

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I'm trying to click on a sidebar that has the following structure:

```
<div class=“sidebar”>
  <nav class=“subnav”>
    <ul>
      <li>
    <a class=“subnav-toggle”></a>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li class=subnav-item>…</li>
        <li class=subnav-item>…</li>
        <li class=subnav-item>…</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
      </li>
      <li>…</li>
      <li>…</li>
      <li>…</li>
      <li>…</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

and I created the following page model:

(Note: I want to get the higher level menu items on the navbar, not the second level `<li>`)

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

export class PageModel {
  constructor () {
    this.firstItem = Selector('.subnav > ul > li').nth(0);
    this.secondItem = Selector('.subnav > ul > li').nth(1);
    ...
  }
}
```

finally, my test script is as follows:

```
import { PageModel } from 'myclass';

const a_item = new PageModel();
...
test ('Sample test', async t => {
  await t
    .hover(a_item.firstItem);
});
```

Testcafe successfuly hovers over the element I selected. However, I get an error saying that `TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of null`.

How do I solve this issue?

** Update **

I updated my query based on a query that I put on the console.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.subnav > ul > li')
NodeList(8) [li, li, li, li, li, li, li, li]
```

Comment: It looks as if there is no 'second item' that matches that selector.

Comment: @Meg I can find the elements using the console. I updated my question to reflect the query, but the same error appears

Comment: So I see that in your console query you have .subnav, but in your testcode you don't have the "."; Is it as simple as a typo?

Comment: Unfortunately not, it was a typo

Comment: Okay.  Can you select OTHER things on the page without getting this error?  I begin to suspect that it's not directly related to these lines, since the hover itself does work.  Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37360202/uncaught-in-promise-typeerror-cannot-read-property-createelement-of-undefin and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014090/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-appendchild-of-null

Comment: It looks like a TestCafe problem. Could please share an example which I can reproduce on my machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your selector,

```
Selector('subnav').find('li > a').nth(0);
```

you are selecting the first A that is the immediate child of a LI that is somewhere under "subnav".

I think what you actually want to do is find the li elements of the "outer" list, like this:

```
 Selector('.subnav > ul > li').nth(0);
```

Comment: This answer reflected the question before an edit-- I will update, or remove if I can't answer properly.

Comment: I am able to select the element using that selector, but I'm still getting the error. I also tried creating a selector and using a `querySelectorAll()`, but I get the same error.

Comment: The error is related to the button I was clicking on my page. I will figure it out, but clicking on other buttons on the navbar work